# Regex for an arbitrary "name: amount" string

Tags: javascript, regex

Help to figure out how to parse arbitrary `Name[:-] amount unit` string where a colon or a dash is optional as a delimiter.

Basically, I need to lookup backwards and find a pair of an amount and a unit of measurement and assume everything else before but colon or dash (if present) is a name.

Like this:

`'Item 1lb'` -> `'Item', '1', 'lb'`

`'Item 2: 3kg'` -> `'Item 2', '3', 'kg'`

`'Something else 2 - 6 oz'` -> `'Something else 2', '6', 'oz'`

`'Even more complex-2 90 karat'` -> `'Even more complex-2', '90', 'karat'`

The idea is to parse as sloppy input as possible.

Answer (score 1):

not very robust, but to match your test cases:

https://regex101.com/r/zhuaYV/1

```
^(.*?)[:-\s]+(\d+)\s*(\w*)$
```

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression like this might work

```
(.*): ([0-9]*)(.*)
```

This should return 3 groups for each of the terms. You may have to play around with the expression depending on how messy the input is.